# Retrieve Control/select value with XPath in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, list, xpath, drop-down-menu, filter

A form is populated from a list and I need it filtered. I have a table with a date column and would like to display only the rows of the required month. For this I have used XPath filtering:

```
[((ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@MyDateColumn) ,1061 ,'MM'))=02)]
```

This gives me the results for February, all ok. Now what I am trying to achieve is to make the month selectable with a drop-down list:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="DropDownList1">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="01">January
        </asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="02">February</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

The drop-down can also be a regular html select if it would help, no difference there. But how can I retrieve the chosen value of the *select* with XPath?

Trying to achieve this with XPath because SharePoint's "regular" filtering only allows filtering by full date, not by day, month or year separately.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah great, my long answer and connection error! Being shorter this time:

I just wanted to filter form/table rows by month. For this I created an ASP.NET Control DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem Value="01">January</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="02">February</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="03">March</asp:ListItem>

    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Now to filter my DataFormWebPart by the date column, I first created a parameter. A parameter can be easily created when choosing *Filter* for the form and under the *Value* column choosing *Create new parameter...*. Just created a parameter MyParameter from Controls:DropDownList1. Now this parameter can be used in XPath filtering:

```
[((ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@MyDateColumn) ,1061 ,'MM'))=$MyParameter)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you have this XML document** (the ASP text in the question isn't well-formed XML):

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected" value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

**and selection `$m`, then this XPath expression**:

```
/*/*[@value=$m]/text()
```

**selects the wanted text-node** that corresponds to `$m`.

The XPath expression above reads:

*Select all text nodes that are children of any element whose `value` attribute is equal to the value of `$m` and that is a child of the top element of the document.*

For example:

```
/*/*[@value=7]/text()
```

**selects the text node**

`"July"`

and

```
/*/*[.=$v]/@value
```

for example:

```
/*/*[.='July']/@value
```

selects the `value` attribute, equal to `7`.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain myself clearly, but I want to get the value of such a list that you posted, not set it. I need for filtering SharePoint List data.

Comment: @Indrek: Sorry, The XPath expression *is* getting you the value: "July" for 7. Can you explain?

Comment: I need to get the value of the selected list in an Xpath filter (I'm using the select to control which data is shown).

Comment: So, you need to get 7 for July? The reverse?

Comment: Yes (and 'Yes' once more for min comment length).

Comment: @Indrek: I have edited my answer -- now you have it both ways.